# Accessing object member variable values in .net using an enum

Tags: .net, reflection, properties

[EDITED to remove the implication that I needed to access .net properties (vice member variables)]

I'm trying to create a design pattern using .net (WPF coded in C# to be specific) by which instances of a class (derived from a base class) have member variables that can be accessed by passing an enum value in a method call.  For example `myObject.GetValueOf(dimensionFields.Latitude)` would return the "Latitude" value held by myObject.  Obviously the purpose is to use `GetValueOf([some enum variable])` at runtime to access any of a number of field values defined by an enumeration.  I also need fairly high performance as these values will be accessed when many (could easily be well over 100,000) objects are drawn to a display (via OpenGL).

Because of the performance requirements, I'm reluctant to use reflection--is that a reasonable reluctance?

I have a solution in mind, but my question is: "is their a better or easier way?"

Here's my current solution:  I'll create enumerations for each type of member variable I want to access (i.e., one for doubles, one for integers, one for strings, one for bools, etc).  The base class for my objects will have dictionaries corresponding to each type of variable (e.g., `Dictionary<FieldsForDoubles, double> m_doubleDict`).  A `GetValueOf([some enum value])` method in that base class will be overloaded to accept each type of enumeration and return the appropriate data type (e.g., `public double GetValueOf(FieldsForDoubles field)`).  Derived classes can add actual properties for convenience (e.g., a `Latitude` property), but those properties will simply access the appropriate dictionary.

Finally, as an excursion, I might make the dictionaries accessible by a string value rather than an enum value, have the `GetValueOf` method access the dictionaries by using `someEnumValue.ToString()` and provide a generic method (`GetVaueOf<type>(string variableName)`) to allow certain derived classes to hold variables NOT in the current enumerations but accessible with a very similar pattern (e.g., I can use `GetValueOf<double>([some variable name])` to access any variable that uses this pattern)

Anyone see issues with this method (e.g., accessing fairly short dictionaries isn't THAT expense, right?)?  Any other thoughts on how this might be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just keep everything in a dictionary and use the enumeration as a key? Is there a compelling reason for there to be properties at all?

Comment: I think my title and description may have been misleading.  By "property" I really just meant any variable held by the class.  My current thinking as described above is to use dictionaries as you suggest.  Any related properties, if desired, would be added by derived classes for convenience of access.

Comment: So instead of using reflection, you want to reinvent it?  I don't know the performance difference between reflection and using a dictionary to store the values, but I can't imagine there being much of a gap.  If it was that fast, then wouldn't .NET be doing that on the back end?

Answer (score 0):

If I am way off just tell me and I will delete.  Why does the data need to be properties, enumerations, and dictionaries?   Why not just a dictionary as in the comment by vcsjones?  You start with properties and then refer to field "number of field values".   It is not clear what you want.  Do you plan to build the enumeration and properties at run time - if so how do you plan to do that?

Possible simplified approach.

```
public class dynamicClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> DicString { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Int32>  DicInt32  { get; private set; }

    public string GetStringFromKey(string key) { return DicString[key]; }
```

I don't see what GetStringFromKey brings to the table.

At the client DicString[key]; versus GetStringFromKey(key);

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think my title and description may have been misleading.  By "property" I really just meant any variable held by the class.  You're pattern is pretty much what I'm thinking of, though I'd add a generalized access method like `GetValueOf([some variable])`.

Comment: Then please edit your question.  On SO most people will read property as a formal a .NET property.   I don't see what GetValueOf brings to the table?

Answer (score 0):

(First, a non-answer)
Personally, I would work on developing a way around the need to recreate reflection. Direct property references are always faster because they hold the memory address. Any kind of redirection or lookup is always going to be more expensive.

(Here's an answer)
Obviously we don't know your requirements or system, so here's a thought. If your properties are defined in an enum, then in theory they are not being created at run-time. So rather than using a Dictionary, why not just use an array? If you have

```
enum
  prop1 = 0
  prop2 = 1
  prop3 = 2
```

Then all you need is an array of length 3. When the user passes an enum, use it as an index into your array.

EDIT: If performance is your main driver, then you'd need to create a different enum for each type of variable so that your array can be "strongly" typed (non-object). You'll then need a different function for each type. So:

```
enum intProp
  prop1 = 0
  prop2 = 1
  prop3 = 2

enum floatProp
  prop1 = 0
  prop2 = 1
  prop3 = 2

int[] intVals
float[] floatVals

fun int getIntProp(intProp p)
  return intVals[(int)p]

fun float getFloatProp(floatProp p)
  return floatVals[(int)p]
```

It's not pretty, but it should be fast enough to handle 100,000 objects. Unfortunately, we must often balance performance and maintainability. This is ugly code, but nice neat code is nearly always going to carry a performance hit.

If you want true lightning performance, your best bet is to go with C++ and managing addresses directly.